# Trying to parse code with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to parse the code

```
  <p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'mso-layout-grid-align:none'><span style=3D'font-size:
8.0pt'>$</span><span lang=3DEN-US style=3D'font-size:8.0pt;mso-ansi-language:
  EN-US'>ogrnNomer</span><span style=3D'font-size:8.0pt'>$</span><span
  style=3D'font-size:8.0pt;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow;mso-fareast-language:
  RU'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

with regular expression

```
(<((?!<).)*(:\n)((?!<).)*>)*(((?!<).)*)(<\/(((?!<).)*)>)*
```

I expected to get 4 matches with 5 groups for each match.

For example, for match

```
<span style=3D'font-size:
8.0pt'>$</span>
```

I expected

1 Group:

```
<span style=3D'font-size
```

2 Group:

```
:(with line break)
```

3 Group:

```
8.0pt'>
```

4 Group:

```
$
```

5 Group:

```
</span>
```

But I can't achieve this with my regular expression.

How my regular expression should look?

My example available here https://regex101.com/r/5LA8J0/1

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: Try `(<(\w+)[^>]*?)(:\n?)([^>]*>)([^<>]*)(<\/\2>)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LA8J0/2). Group 2 is a "technical" group to match the tag name.

Comment: Oh, thank you, but this task has been solved about month ago )))